# Weird Character added to footer of email, encoding issue?

Tags: email, outlook, exchange-server

I have some employees getting weird characters getting added to the end of their emails, here is a snippet.

䐼噉氠湡㵧湥甭⁳汣獡㵳畏汴潯䵫獥慳敧效摡牥愠楬湧∽敬瑦•䥄㵒䰢剔㸢㰠但呎䘠捡㵥䌢•楓敺㈽ⴾ䈼㹒㰠㹂㱆䈯‾⁂㰠剂‾䈼匾⼼㹂圠䈼㹒㰠㹂㱔䈯‾㱍剂‾㰠㹂㱓䈯‾㱒剂‾†⼼但呎‾⼼䥄㹖䐼噉㰾䐯噉

has anyone experienced this and does anyone have a solution

Comment: content encoding issue; https://superuser.com/questions/1114966/chinese-letters-showing-up-when-replying-to-email-in-outlook

Comment: Lol so encoding issue but no solution on the thread?

Comment: I got it solved with upgrading my Exchange Server to the latest version. Which version are you running?

Comment: office 365 so its not my exchange server to run. I can use the admin panel but I dont believe that allows me to do that.

Comment: related: https://superuser.com/questions/1114966/chinese-letters-showing-up-when-replying-to-email-in-outlook

Comment: Thank you I havent found a specific answer as to why this is occurring but I have found that it is an outlook encoding error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook encoding error rendering the wrong characters because of the wrong encoding